# Ruby Set include function returning true even when item is not in set

Tags: ruby, md5

I am writing a program that searches from tweets and images to combine the two. I have a built in two arrays that hold MD5 hashes of the tweets used and the uri's of the images used which I check against before using results from a new search so I don't use the same thing again.

Here is the code I use to check if the tweet contains characters I don't want or isn't in the set of MD5 hashes

```
unless (/@/.match(tweet[0]) or /http/.match(tweet[0]) or /^#/.match(tweet[0]) or md5list.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(tweet[0])))
```

where md5list is the set which gets populated like this

```
md5list << "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(tweet[0])}"
```

but `md5list.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(tweet[0]))` seems to always return true, even when the arrays are empty

Can anyone spot where I'm messing up here?
Thanks

Edit:

The set contains a number of MD5 hashes of strings of text, I want to search this set for a hash of a random string i have and only execute code if it isn't already present in the set.

To do this I've used, essentially, `unless (set.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest("test")`
which should return true if the set does include it, and false if it does not. I have tested this in irb and it seems to work

```
irb(main):009:0> s = Set.new
=> #<Set: {}>
irb(main):010:0> s << Digest::MD5.hexdigest("test")
=> #<Set: {"9cdfb439c7876e703e307864c9167a15"}>
irb(main):011:0> s.include?("test")
=> false
irb(main):012:0> s.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest("test"))
=> true
irb(main):013:0> s.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest("test2"))
=> false
```

but in my implementation it seems to always return true.

**EDIT**

Some, uh more, stuff. (here is the full code, I'll try not to post to huge chunks: https://github.com/rolandshoemaker/bleak-tweets/blob/master/bleak-tweet.rb)

this is the function that is failing. it should search for an image, and only if the md5 hash of the uri isn't already in the imagemd5 set it will retreieve the image, do some stuff, then add the md5 hash of the uri to the set so that the same image won't be used again.

```
def imageSearch(tag, tweet, imagemd5)
    Google::Search::Image.new(:query => tag).each do |image|
        unless (imagemd5.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(image.uri)))
            filename = String.new
            open(image.uri) { |f|
                File.open("current", "wb") do |file|
                    file.puts f.read
                end
                img = Magick::Image::read("current").first
                img.resize_to_fit!(600, 600)
                drawable = Magick::Draw.new

                drawable.pointsize = 18.0
                #drawable.gravity = Magick::SouthEastGravity
                drawable.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight

                tm = drawable.get_type_metrics(img, tweet)
                drawable.fill = 'black'
                #drawable.opacity(1)
                xy1 = [0, (((img.rows)*6)/10)]
                xy2 = [(((img.columns)*8)/10), (((img.rows)*9)/10)]


                drawable.rectangle(xy1[0],xy1[1],xy2[0],xy2[1])
                drawable.draw(img)

                position = xy1[1]+10
                wraptext(tweet, ((xy2[0]-xy1[0])-10)/10).each do |row|
                    drawable.annotate(img,(xy2[0]-xy1[0])-10,(xy2[1]-xy1[1])-10,10,position += 15,row) {self.fill='white'}
                end
                filename = "testy." << img.format
                img.write(filename)
            }
            puts imagemd5.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(image.uri)).inspect
            imagemd5 << "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(image.uri)}"
            puts imagemd5.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(image.uri)).inspect
            tumblrPost(tag, filename)
            File.delete(filename)
            File.delete("current")
            break
        end
    end
end
```

this outputs an image and in the console outputs this (with an example tweet)

```
Damn this swollen ankle. Smh #injured #painful
false
true
```

the problem is that, in this case, the image that the program used was one that had already been used and yet `imagemd5.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(image.uri)` is returning false where it should be true

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I see your update, but as I said in my response to your comment below, you'll need to show your code, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Perhaps part of my confusion is around your statement "even when the arrays are empty". I'm not sure what arrays you are referring to, but I did assume that you added the expression you are checking for to the set before doing `include?`.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, it seems like you're questioning why:

```
["#{foo}"].include?(foo)
```

is always true where `foo` is the expression `MD5.hexdigest(tweet[0])`. But the above expression will always be true as long as `foo` returns a string, which `MD5.hexdigest` does.

Comment: huh, I tried this in irb and it seems to work?

`irb(main):009:0> s = Set.new`
`=> #<Set: {}>`
`irb(main):010:0> s << Digest::MD5.hexdigest("lol")`
`=> #<Set: {"9cdfb439c7876e703e307864c9167a15"}>`
`irb(main):011:0> s.include?("lol")`
`=> false`
`irb(main):012:0> s.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest("lol"))`
`=> true`
`irb(main):013:0> s.include?(Digest::MD5.hexdigest("bad"))`
`=> false`

Comment: I don't get your "huh". Your question indicated that `include?` always returned `true` for your sample case, but your sample case involved checking for the same thing that was added to your `Set`. (I mistakenly showed you code involving an `Array`, but your irb sample shows that `Set` behaved the same way.) You got `false` when the expressions were different. I guess you'll have to do what the comment suggested, provide the code, expected output and actual output.

Comment: ah okay, Sorry, I guess my example was backward, I am doing this within a fuction, in the code the include? check is made before adding the md5 hash to the set and only if it is not already in the set code is executed and it is added so that the code is executed for the same md5 hash twice. (the entire code for the file is here: https://github.com/rolandshoemaker/bleak-tweets/blob/master/bleak-tweet.rb)

Comment: So what evidence do you have that the `include?` is always returning true? In other words, what output are you seeing vs. what you're expecting?

Comment: Sorry that was my fault, I had put where i was looking after I had added it stupidly so it would always return true, I added an output before I did and updated my question with what seems to actually be the problem... (i think, i've not used in ruby for a long long time ._.)

Comment: Ok, well now I have to ask why you are confident that the digest was in the set before you added it. Perhaps you can print out the Set in the case that you don't find it when you think you should have?